# Javascript function only works on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.navLinkovi');
const otvorenMeni = document.querySelector('#otvoren');
const zatvorenMeni = document.querySelector('#zatvoren');

const otvoriMeni = () => {
    nav.style.display = 'flex';
    otvorenMeni.style.display = 'none';
    zatvorenMeni.style.display = 'inline-block';
}

otvoren.addEventListener('click', otvoriMeni);

const zatvoriMeni = () => {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
    otvorenMeni.style.display = 'inline-block';
    zatvorenMeni.style.display = 'none';
}

zatvoren.addEventListener('click', zatvoriMeni);
```

```css
:root {
    --color-primary: #FF7000;

    --color-primary-variant: #e5a55d;
    --color-bg-1: #000e17;
    --color-bg-2: #001e2d;
    --color-bg-3: #012734;
    --color-bg-4: #003347;
    --color-light: #85a2b2;
    --color-white: #fff;

    --container-width-lg: 88%;
    --container-width-md: 92%;

    --transition: all 400ms ease;
}

@font-face { font-family: Poppins; src: url('Poppins-Regular.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Poppins; font-weight: regular; src: url('Poppins-Regular.ttf');}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #012734;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

h1, h2 {
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FF7000;
}

.kontejner {
    width: 88%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 2160px;;
}

img {
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.nav2 {
    background-color: #001e2d;
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #003347;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navKontejner {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.navMeni {
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.navMeni img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.logo {
    width: 5.5rem;
}

.navLinkovi {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4rem;
}

.navSkrol {
    background-color: #001e2d;
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #003347;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.slajdovi {
    display: none;
}

.slajdovi img {
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.slajder {
    max-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px
}

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #001e2d;
    border-top: 0.5rem solid #003347;
}

.headerKontejner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 40%;
    gap: 10%;
    position: relative;
}

.headerSlika {
    width: 29rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 8rem;
}

.desno {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.desno h1 {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgb(78, 81, 230);
}

.desno p {
    width: 85%;
}

footer {
    border-top: 0.5rem solid #003347;
}

.footerKontejner {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.footerLinkovi {
    margin: 3rem 0 5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5rem;
}

/* ---------- O MENI ---------- */

.omeniKontejner {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    padding-left: 250px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 26rem auto;
    gap: 3rem;
    position: relative;
}

.naslov {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7rem;
    left: 7rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

.omeniSlika {
    position: relative;
}

.slikaIza {
    width: 16rem;
    height: 24rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #003347;
}

.slikaVelika {
    position: relative;
    left: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    filter: saturate(0) brightness(0.3);
    transition: 500ms ease;
}

.slikaMala {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    left: 8rem;
    height: 22rem;
    width: 22rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 2rem 2rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 500ms ease;
}

.omeniSlika:hover .slikaMala {
    opacity: 0;
}

.omeniSlika:hover .slikaVelika {
    filter: saturate(1) brightness(1);
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 1rem solid #003347;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}


.omeniDesno {
    margin-left: 10rem;
}

.omeniDesno p {
    margin: 0 4rem 1.5rem 0rem;
    width: 60%;
}

/* ---------- GALERIJA ---------- */

.galerijaKontejner {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

.galerija {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 3rem;
}

.galerija img {
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.galerija article {
    border: 0.5rem solid #003347;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.galerija article:hover img {
    box-shadow: 0 4rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* ---------- KONTAKT ---------- */

.kontakt {
    margin-top: 130px;
}

form {
    background: #003347;
    width: 640px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    max-width: 97%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 55px 30px;
}

.kontaktNaslov h2 {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.polovina {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.stavka {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    width: 48%;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.polovina input {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.celo {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.celo textarea {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.dugme {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.dugme input {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.dugme input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]{
    background: white;
    color: black;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.dugme input:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.stavka input:focus, .celo textarea:focus{
    background: #025069;
}

.ikonice {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.ikonice img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

/* ---------- RESPONZIVNOST (tablet) ---------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .kontejner {
        width: 92%;
        position: relative;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    .navLinkovi {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .navLinkovi li {
        height: 5rem;
        box-shadow: -3rem 3rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

    .navLinkovi li a {
        background: #003347;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1rem 5rem 1rem 3rem;
        border-top: 1px solid #001e2d;
    }

    .navMeni {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #zatvoren {
        display: none;
    }

    .slajdovi img {
        max-width: 600px;
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    header {
        height: fit-content;
        padding: 14rem 0 12rem;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
    }

    .headerKontejner {
        grid-template-columns: 40% 54%;
        gap: 6%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .headerSlika {
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .desno p {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .omeniKontejner {
        grid-template-columns: 40% 54%;
        gap: 6%;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    .slikaIza, .slikaMala {
        display: none;
    }

    .slikaVelika {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        filter: saturate(1) brightness(1);
    }

    .slikaVelika:hover {
        border: none;
    }

    .omeniDesno {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .omeniDesno p {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .galerijaKontejner {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .galerija {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }


}

/* ---------- RESPONZIVNOST (telefon) ---------- */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    
    h1, h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }

    .slajdovi img {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 180px;
    }

    header {
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 6rem;
    }

    .headerKontejner {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        gap: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .headerSlika {
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 7rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .desno p {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .omeniKontejner {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        gap: 2rem;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 230px;
    }

    .omeniDesno p {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .omeniSlika {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .slikaVelika {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .slikaIza, .slikaMala {
        display: none;
    }

    .omeniSlika:hover .slikaVelika {
        filter: saturate(1) brightness(1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .polovina {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .stavka {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .dugme {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .dugme input {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    } 

    .footer h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .footer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .footerLinkovi {
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 1rem;
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }
}

/* ---------- SVETLA TEMA ---------- */

.dark-mode {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nikola Photo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="kontejner navKontejner">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="slike/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <ul class="navLinkovi">
                <li><a href="index.html">Pocetna</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerija.html ">Galerija</a></li>
                <li><a href="omeni.html">O meni</a></li>
                <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navMeni" id="otvoren"><img src="slike/hamburger.png" alt=""></button>
            <button class="navMeni" id="zatvoren"><img src="slike/xicon.png" alt=""></button>
        </div>
    </nav> 

    <div class="slajder">
        <div class="slajdovi">
            <img src="slike/slika10.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slajdovi">
            <img src="slike/slika11.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slajdovi">
            <img src="slike/slika17.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <header id="header">
        <div class="kontejner headerKontejner">
            <div class="levo">
                <div class="headerSlika">
                    <img src="slike/slika8.png" alt="pariz">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desno">
                <h1>NikolaPhoto</h1><br>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente ut praesentium assumenda cum et? Fugit quae dolor animi enim eveniet, alias hic nulla eius nam accusamus facilis asperiores rerum odit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <footer>
        <div class="kontejner footerKontejner">
            <div class="footer">
                <h2 class="footerNaslov">kontakt@nikolaphoto.com</h2>
            </div>
            <ul class="footerLinkovi">
                <li><a href="index.html">Pocetna</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerija.html ">Galerija</a></li>
                <li><a href="omeni.html">O meni</a></li>
                <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="themeToggle()">Theme Toggle</button><div id="theme"></div>
    </footer>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a javascript function that opens/closes hamburger menu, works fine on the main page, but doesn't work on any other page. All the pages use the same nav (that includes the hamburger buttons) and same js file.
Gave the code to a friend and works fine on his site.

EDIT: In the original post I included a completely wrong js function, changed it now.

This code for the snippet seems to work (hamburger is in the top left) and it does work for me but as I said only on the main page, I have 3 more pages with the same nav where it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Can you share the file(s) this html and function are included?

Comment: Where is element with name 'slajdovi' ?

Comment: Probably not related, but you have some invalid HTML. `<img src="slike/hamburger.png" alt=""></i>` that image has a closing `</i>` tag for some reason.

Comment: @Christian Sure, I'm gonna edit the post real quick.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @CherryDT no, only for the slider function, but its normal since I dont have the slider on any other page so its undefined.

Comment: Well if that's a crash then it will stop any following code from working too. It's not "normal" - it should never crash, you should add a condition around the code so it will only run if the slider exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should include js file inside head tag if you didn't already do that.
2. There may be no elements containing a class name of *"slajdovi"*. check with console.log if function is ran.

happy coding!

Comment: Yeah I included the wrong function somehow, it was like 2am so I was probably too tired, but heres the right function for the hamburger menu.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a new js file for the hamburger menu function and including that one in all of the pages seems to fix it, I have no idea why it doesn't work when I use the same function in the main js file.